# How do I center text when exporting an Org file to an .odt file?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to know how to center the text in a file exported from Org-mode to .odt

Example of what I want:

```
* TODO center text
```

--->

```
                               * DONE center text
```

Bonuses if it will automatically center when I type, or press enter.

Edit: I want to do this and then export to odt.

Comment: Why would yoiu want that in **org**-mode?? Do you actually want this in exported output?

Comment: Yes actually, I want to export my org files as odt files for scripts for games and animations.

Answer (score 9):

Although you cannot center headings (lines starting from *'s), `#+BEGIN_CENTER` ~ `#+END_CENTER` can center parts of the document.

Usage:
test.org

```
#+TITLE: Test

#+BEGIN_CENTER
- [ ] Hoge
- [X] Fuga
#+END_CENTER
```

Then export to ODT in your workflow.
This will result in the bullet points being centered in the produced ODT file.

Answer (score 1):

You can center lines with the command `center-line` (`M-o M-s`).  Other options include `center-paragraph` and `center-region`.

However, you should probably not use this command on `org-mode` headers.  Headers are only recognized as such when the asterisks begin at the first column, so centering one turns it into plain text.

Comment: Yes, this works, but when I export this to odt it doesn't center. I just edited my original post to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  Are you benefiting from centering the text in Emacs?  As Dan points out, that can break a lot of Org's parsing assumptions.

If you can accept a solution that leaves the headlines left-aligned in Org but centers the text in the exported ODT, have a look at [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Applying-custom-styles.html#Applying-custom-styles) part of the manual.  Paraphrasing:

- Create a sample example.org file and export it to ODT.
- Open the example.odt using LibreOffice.
- Use the Stylist (F11 on my system) to locate the target styles—you probably want `Heading` (for all headings) or `Heading N` (for some depth N)—and modify those to be center-aligned.
- Save the modified file either as an OpenDocument Text (.odt) or OpenDocument Template (.ott) file.
- Back in Emacs, if you want to center headlines in every exported file by default, customize the variable `org-odt-styles-file` and point it to the newly created file.  If you only want to center headlines in a few files, insert `#+ODT_STYLES_FILE: "new file"` at the top of just the files you want to affect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to center the title in exported odt file,

open the exporting odt file with Emacs, in the opened buffer, select content.xml and press `Enter` key.

In content.xml, say you want to center the level 1 heading, find text `text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_1"` search and replace it with `"text:h text:style-name="NewHeading_1"`.

then scroll back, move the focus inside tag `<office:automatic-styles>`, insert below code,

```
<style:style style:name="NewHeading_1" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Heading_20_1">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
</style:style>
```

Save and exit Emacs.